# Grep removing lines that are sem-similar?

Tags: regex, linux, unix

I am reading a file like so:

```
cat access_logs | grep Ruby
```

To determine what IP's are accessing one of my files.  It returns a huge list.  I want to remove semi-duplicates, i.e. these two lines are technically the same- except have different time/date stamps.  In a massive list with thousands of repeats- is there a way to only get unique ip addresses?

```
1.2.3.4 - - [13/Apr/2014:14:20:17 -0400] "GET /color.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 207 "-" "Ruby"
1.2.3.4 - - [13/Apr/2014:14:20:38 -0400] "GET /color.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 207 "-" "Ruby"
1.2.3.4 - - [13/Apr/2014:15:20:17 -0400] "GET /color.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 207 "-" "Ruby"
1.2.3.4 - - [13/Apr/2014:15:20:38 -0400] "GET /color.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 207 "-" "Ruby"
```

So that for example those 4 lines would be trimmed into only one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk '/Ruby/ && !seen[$1]++' access_logs
```

This will print only first line for each IP address even if timestamp is different for a given IP.

For your input it prints:

```
1.2.3.4 - - [13/Apr/2014:14:20:17 -0400] "GET /color.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 207 "-" "Ruby"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
awk '/Ruby/{print $1}' file | sort -u
```

Or you can use `grep` + `cut` to get first column as suggested in the comment.